# How to add read more in wordpress

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I have tried many things but i didn't get Read more `link` in `paragraph`

*page.php*

```
<?php
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'post', 'posts_per_page' => 10 );
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
    echo '<div class="inner-box-post">'; 
    echo '<h2><a href="get_permalink();">';
     the_title();
    echo '</a></h2>';
     echo '<div class="thumbnail">';
      the_post_thumbnail( 'thumbnail' ); 
      get_comments( $args ); 
     echo '</div>';
     echo '<div class="post-containt">';
     echo '<div class="post-date"><strong>';
     echo get_the_date();
     echo '</strong> </div>';
     echo the_excerpt();  ;
     echo  '</div> ';
     echo '</div>';
     endwhile; ?>
 </div>
```

*function.php*

```
function new_excerpt_more($output) {
    return $output . '<p><a href="'. get_permalink() . '">' . 'Read more &raquo' . '</a></p>';
}
add_filter('get_the_excerpt', 'new_excerpt_more');
```

Comment: You don't need that amount of `echo` in your code. Just use open and closing php tags correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filter is `excerpt_more`,

```
add_filter('excerpt_more', 'new_excerpt_more');
```

*[Reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_the_Read_More)*.

Comment: But `[…]` showing because of `excerpt` . Then how can i remove it ?

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
            $args = array( 'post_type' => 'post', 'posts_per_page' => 10 );
            $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
                while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
    ?>
        <div class="inner-box-post">
            <h2><a href="get_permalink();"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>

            <div class="thumbnail">
                <?php the_post_thumbnail( 'thumbnail' ); ?>
                <?php get_comments( $args ); ?>
            </div>

        <div class="post-containt">
            <div class="post-date">
                <strong><?php echo get_the_date(); ?></strong> 
            </div>
            <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
        </div>
     </div>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
```

Remove [...] and add read more option using

```
function new_excerpt_more($output) {
    $output = rtrim($output,'[...]');
    return $output . '<p><a href="'. get_permalink() . '">' . 'Read more >>' . '</a></p>';

}
add_filter('excerpt_more', 'new_excerpt_more');
```

[image]

Comment: you can use  <?php get_the_date(); ?> above use ans but there remaining  'echo' so use <?php echo get_the_date(); ?>

Comment: Thanks Ravi, +1 for You  :)

Answer (score 1):

**THIS IS NOT AN ANSWER, JUST CORRECTIONS**

You really don't need to overuse `echo` in your code. Just use opening and closing php tags correctly. Rather use this. It also helps with readibility

```
<?php
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'post', 'posts_per_page' => 10 );
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
?>
    <div class="inner-box-post">
    <h2><a href="get_permalink();"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <?php the_post_thumbnail( 'thumbnail' ); ?>
     <?php get_comments( $args ); ?>
     </div>
     <div class="post-containt">
     <div class="post-date"><strong>
     <?php get_the_date(); ?>
     </strong> </div>
     <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
     </div>
     </div>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
 </div>
```